# JavaFX | how to get "getVisibleAmount()" value from ScrollPane

Tags: java, javafx, scrollbar, fxml, scrollpane

i has been trying to get value [getVisibleAmount()](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollBar.html#getVisibleAmount()) from ScrollPane, which ScrollPane has a child AnchorPane and ScrollBar. in this case i want to get ScrollBar child from ScrollPane to getVisibleAmount() function. where this function only on ScrollBar component.

i want applying getVisibleAmount() from ScrollPane child(ScrollBar) to different ScrollBar separately.

i'm sorry my english it's not really good, maybe this picture can helping what i'm trying to achieve.
[image]

Any solution will be appreciated. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a method to get the visible amount from a `ScrollPane`'s `ScrollBar`:

```java
static double getScrollBarVisibleAmount(ScrollPane scrollPane, Orientation orientation) {
    for (Node node : scrollPane.lookupAll(".scroll-bar")) {
        if (node instanceof ScrollBar) {
            ScrollBar scrollBar = (ScrollBar) node;
            if (scrollBar.getOrientation() == orientation) {
                return scrollBar.getVisibleAmount();
            }
        }
    }
    return -1.0;
}
```

You can use it like this:

```java
double amount = getScrollBarVisibleAmount(myScrollPane, Orientation.VERTICAL);
```

You need to know exactly when to call this method as the `ScrollPane` might not have been shown at the time of calling. It also will be easier to track the changes if you assign a `ChangeListener<Number>`:

```java
scrollBar.visibleAmountProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> System.out.println("New visible amount: " + newValue));
```